# microcredit or microfinance data

Tags: data-request, economics

**Data**: I am seeking a panel style data set containing information on microfinance. I am aware of large studies around Bangladesh.

**Context**: I am attempting to undertake a research project on the influence of microfinance.

**License:** Any licenses are acceptable.

Comment: please consider expanding your question with this [template](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/284/1511) in order to get more attention.

Comment: Relevant: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5424/where-can-i-find-asset-finance-or-microfinance-data-at-the-individual-loan-reci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked USAID's [Microenterprise Results Reporting (MRR) Portal](https://eads.usaid.gov/mrr/)?  You may also be able to find other resources at [USAID's Development Data Library](http://www.usaid.gov/data).
[usaidopen](/questions/tagged/usaidopen)

Answer (score 1):

The world bank has a lot of useful information and make a lot of their datasets accessible. [This link](http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTDEC/EXTRESEARCH/0,,contentMDK:21470820~pagePK:64214825~piPK:64214943~theSitePK:469382,00.html) has information on a longitudinal study in Bangladesh. This site also presents a host of other, similar datasets.