# Where can I find asset finance or microfinance data at the individual (loan recipient) level?

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm looking for asset finance and microfinance data at the individual level.  I'm already aware of Kiva, Prosper and Lending Club (links below).

Specifically, I'd like to find individual loan repayment histories and sociodemographic details from a variety of microfinance products.  If developing world, even better; if sub-saharan Africa, best!

Here's what I've found so far:
Lending Club:
https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action
Prosper:
https://www.prosper.com/tools/DataExport.aspx
Kiva:
https://build.kiva.org/

Can you help me add to the above list?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you download Prosper's data export? I just get 'connection timeout' while trying to download `ProsperDataExport_xml.zip`.

Comment: this kaggle loan dataset maybe useful: https://www.kaggle.com/zhijinzhai/loandata

Answer (score 2):

[lendvious](http://www.lendvious.com) has this sort of data; seem to have it at the credit score / platform level. I'm not sure if you could get to the individual level, but might be worth a try.

Look at: [Investor Data](https://www.lendvious.com/investor/investor-data)

The platform is just getting started, and there intention does not seem to be to create an 'open' platform. However, it may be worth pinging them to see if they'd be open to your project.

Comment: lendvious looks closed/proprietary - clicking on the get started link -> the get started page has nothing in regards to getting started, except for a contact us link, which is a tale-tell sign that its closed. so this is probably inappropriate for open data, but i could be wrong. also, thanks for trying!

Comment: Based on what I've heard from them, I would certainly think they are just getting started, and their intention is to be charge for the data. That said, it seemed to me worth reaching out to see if they'd be willing to support the project at hand.

Answer (score 1):

For the least developed countries, you should look for microfinance literature in development economics. Papers typically come with open data, and when they don't, you can ask the authors to share it.

A few major sources are:

### Harvard Dataverse

- https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataverse/harvard?q=microfinance

This service hosts a lot of microeconomic data from individual research projects. Each paper comes with data.

### RePEc

- Top 10% Institutions and Economists in the Field of Microfinance https://ideas.repec.org/top/top.mfd.html
- Authors in Microfinance https://ideas.repec.org/i/emfd.html
- G21: Banks; Other Depository Institutions; Micro Finance Institutions; Mortgages https://ideas.repec.org/j/G21.html
- New working papers in the area of Microfinance https://ideas.repec.org/n/nep-mfd/
- Search https://ideas.repec.org/cgi-bin/htsearch?q=Micro+Finance+Institutions

These links lead to a few hundreds of research papers on topic.